# How to convert object array to user defined object in java8

Tags: java

I have object array which contain some values. I want to convert this array of object to user defined custom class.

```
EX : Object[] obj = new Object[4];
     obj[0] = "one";
     obj[1] = "two";
```

It is possible to convert this object to Employee object by setting obj[0] to setFName and obj[1] to setLName using stream api of java8. I tried couple of ways but getting error.

output would be

```
Employee e = Stream.of(Obj).map().....
```

something like above

Comment: This sounds like bad design to me.  If you want to convert an `Object[]` to some custom class, then you could add a constructor to the custom class to do this.

Comment: it can be done with `stream reduce`. But really, it look like bad design.

Comment: i tried same thing but here we are setting v to setFName only, i want to set another value to setLName. any other alternative in java8. Here v representing single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to convert `Object[]` to `Employee` - just do it directly:

```
Employee e  = new Employee();
e.setFirstName(obj[0]);
e.setLastName(obj[1]);
```

You probably need a special constructor which accepts `Object[]`

```
public Employee(Object[] that){
    firstName = obj[0];
    lastName = obj[1];
}
```

If you really want to use something from `java-8` for some reason, you might use `Optional`

```
Employee e = Optional.of(obj).map(o -> { 
     Employee tmp = new Employee(); 
     tmp.setFirstName(o[0]);
     tmp.setLastName(o[1]);
     return tmp; 
}).get();
```

But this doesn't give you any advantage over constructor and it is just more confusing. Even if you have the copy constructor variant with `Optional` make sense only if obj might be null:

```
Employee e = Optional.of(obj).map(o -> new Employee(o))
                     .orElseGet(() -> some default value);
```

Comment: Ya i know how to do it in previous version of java before java8, i was looking for if there any direct conversion in java8.